# C++ template : OKay for VC2005SP1, gcc bails out?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, templates

I'm puzzled here, and kindly request your help. 
VC2005SP1 swallows this (stripped out) code but gcc 4.0.1 bails out... Please point me the obvious mistake ?
TIA!

```
template<typename BCT, typename UIDT>
class Factory
{
public:
    template<typename CT>
    bool Register(UIDT UniqueID)
    {
        if (UniqueID > 10)
            return(false);

        CreateObject2<BCT, CT>;

        return(true);
    }
};


template <typename MC, typename MT>
class Manager : public Factory<MC, MT>
{
public:
    bool RegisterType(const MT Type, const std::string TypeName)
    {
        return Factory<MC, MT>::Register<MC>(Type); // gcc claims "expected primary-expression before '>' at this point
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS is being kind.

`return Factory<MC, MT>::template Register<MC>(Type);` should work under both compilers.

Comment: Wow. 4 mn to get the answer ("::template " did the trick).
I'm impressed.
Oh, and thanks!!

Comment: For the record, the compiler is "supposed" to see Factory<MC, MT>::Register<MC>(Type) without the template as Factory<MC, MT>::Register < MC > (Type). VS tries to be more helpful (arguably more than it should), but that's why g++ choked.

Comment: And, for the record, g++ once had this "feature" but removed it because code written without "template" and "typename" would compile on g++ but not VC at the time, ...